# i’m unsure wether maniy or madhiy came out while fasting

Tags: sawm

i took a nap and wook up and had some desire i tried to get out of my head but it stayed for a while then i went to use the bathroom and forced some pee out and i think i saw some sticky liquid come out (not 100 percent sure) i checked again and couldn’t find anything and left the bathroom and found a wet spot which disapeered after 15 minutes i’m unsure wether i released madhiy or maniy or if i didn’t release anything at all is my fast void or should i continue my fast?

Answer (score 0):

The fast is only void in the case of Ejaculation i.e: Orgasm or the feeling of "gushing" or "spraying" out of semen "with force" followed by physical exhaustion/weakness. This type of semen is called as "Maniy" and requires ghusl as well as voids the fast.

Other than ejaculation, sexual  thoughts and desires lead to "leaking" or "flowing" of prostatic fluid or "pre-ejaculate" called as "Madhiy". This type of fluid does not invalidate the fast and only requires wudu and washing of the place on the body and cloth.

You can now check which one you experienced and do research on "Maniy" and "Madhiy" in detail online.

Allah knows best.